Unable to install and use NodeJS using FNM
I installed FMM on my windows 10 laptop using below command
winget install Schniz.fnm
After installation, I downloaded NodeJS using
fnm install 16.2.0
After this step when I type fnm use 16.2.0 I get below error
error: We can't find the necessary environment variables to replace the Node version. You should setup your shell profile to evaluate fnm env, see https://github.com/Schniz/fnm#shell-setup on how to do this Check out our documentation for more information: https://fnm.vercel.app
I tried below commands in power-shell. But this does not help me :(
fnm env --use-on-cd | Out-String | Invoke-Expression


notepad $profile


@echo off
:: for /F will launch a new instance of cmd so we create a guard to prevent an infnite loop
if not defined FNM_AUTORUN_GUARD (
    set "FNM_AUTORUN_GUARD=AutorunGuard"
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%z IN ('fnm env --use-on-cd') DO CALL %%z
)


Run below command in PowerShell before installing NodeJs -
fnm env --use-on-cd | Out-String | Invoke-Expression

I was getting the same error, was able to install node after I ran it.
Image


This solves both 'fnm use' issue and the 'node' command, Thanks!
Do you know why is this command missing from the short guide on nodejs.org's Windows download section?

When I install nodejs this way. npm -v works but when I close the console and run npm again the term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Switched back to the prebuild installer because this makes no sense to me....

I just used PowerShell and it all worked well.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The (Windows 11) build-in Powershell is outdated (I think its version1.0), and (when following the directions from nodejs site for Windows/winget/fnm) it fails to find npm (although node -v works). Installing the latest Powershell from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases and rerunning it, works perfectly
